# It is not + noun + to infinitive

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, construction, infinitive-constructions

I do know an adjective (without a noun) in this construction can be followed by a to-infinitive, as in:

1. It is not acceptable to kill a goat in that way.
2. It is not good to kill him here.

But, is it also grammatical to insert a noun after the adjective without changing anything else in the construction? As in:

3. It is not **a good job** to kill a goat that way.
4. It's not **a wise decision** to kill him here.

What I am asking about is the construction in which the to-infinitive modifies the adjective+noun, not the one in which the to-infinitive describes the perception of the doer, like:

It is not an easy question (for me) to deal with.

Comment: All your examples are extraposition constructions, where the infinitival clauses do **not** modify the adjectives or nouns, but are extraposed subjects outside the verb phrase.

Comment: Is it okay to put no comma before these extraposed subjects?

Comment: Yes: No comma is required. Your examples are acceptable.

Comment: @BillJ why don't you transform this comment into an answer so that I will be able to choose it as the most satisfying answer?

Comment: Hello, Fadli. It can often be difficult to isolate syntax from semantics in trickier constructions, but it's usually vital. Here, as BillJ explains clearly, your relevant examples are all sentences where the to-infinitival clause is the 'subject' and not a 'modifier' in the sentence (I've highlighted both the well-known term and the one whose meaning is usually not fully grasped by many; both are  precisely (if not always consensually) defined terms in grammar). The extraposed version is more commonly used than the non-extraposed one, perhaps surprisingly (but English doesn't like ...

Comment: long subjects). // Your discounted example (I've tinkered with it to make a more natural-sounding but equivalent sentence) is structurally different. Here, the to-infinitival clause (together with the adjective) arguably mirrors a relative clause:  _It was not a question that was easy to deal with_ / _It was not an easy-to-deal-with question_ (don't use that version – it's just to illustrate the point), and it could be said to modify the adjective.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth thank you, Edwin. I got it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *It is not good / a wise decision* [*to kill him here*].

Your example is acceptable, but the infinitival clause does not modify "good" or "wise decision". This is a subject extraposition construction where the subordinate clause is an extraposed subject, outside the verb phrase.

The non-extraposed equivalent would be:

> [*To kill him here*] *is not good / a wise decision*.

Here, the infinitival clause is not a modifier, but subject of the sentence.

The same applies to your other examples.